# Who can explain mongodb with ssl?

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I created certificates according to the instructions on the official website of MongoDB, but it doesn't work properly.

I have a replica set and self-signed certificates.

I need a full encryption of traffic between replica members. How do I properly set up these replica members? And how do I enter the MongoDB shell?

I created certificates according to the instructions, in 
mongod.conf:

```
sslMode = requireSSL
sslPEMKeyFile = /etc/ssl/mongo.pem ...
```

and try the add the parameter:

```
sslCAFile =  /etc/ssl/mongo.crt
```

and tried to enter:

```
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongo.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/mongo.pem or 
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongo.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/mongo.crt
```

I get the error -  `The server certificate does not match the host name`.

If I use the client certificate then error: `SSL peer certificate validation failed:self signed certificate`.

the Mongod service is up and running. Mongo version - 3.0.2. Centos - 6.5 x64.

I went through a lot of links but haven't found a working solution.

If it is possible can you please give me the steps?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the self signed certificate, you need to use a valid host name in the "Common Name" field, e.g.:

> Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []: host.domain.com

If you want use a domain certificate, you need to change "host" with "*", e.g.:

> Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []: *.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

You can force mongo to ignore the certificate hostname mismatch with the allowInvalidHostnames [configuration option](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/)

> **net.ssl.allowInvalidHostnames**
>
> **Type**: boolean
>
> **Default**: False
>
> New in version 3.0.
>
> When net.ssl.allowInvalidHostnames is true, MongoDB disables the
>   validation of the hostnames in TLS/SSL certificates, allowing mongod
>   to connect to MongoDB instances if the hostname their certificates do
>   not match the specified hostname.
>
> Changed in version 3.0: Most MongoDB distributions now include support
>   for TLS/SSL. See Configure mongod and mongos for TLS/SSL and TLS/SSL
>   Configuration for Clients for more information about TLS/SSL and
>   MongoDB.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you abstracted a summary of the relevant portions of the linked web page.